# DAX - ALL function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

Does ALL function ignore filters applied in Power Query? Say that I want to count rows, say number 2, in a specific column (x_channel), but that number is filtered out because of a filter in another column (associate.name) in the same table. I'm trying to use ALL function, but the measure doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
Telefon = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), ticket[x_channel]=2, ALL(TICKET[ASSOCIATE.name]), USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))
```

Thanks!

Comment: no, it's ignore only filters applied in the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerQuery (language: M) and PowerBI (language: DAX) have nothing to do with one another.

PowerQuery handles the ingestion of data at refresh time. After that, the only data PowerBI has in its data model is the data that was provided to it by PowerQuery.

If you have filtered data in PowerQuery, then using ALL() in DAX will have no effect.